# Zend Framework Questions

Tags: zend-framework

I have two questions.
First, I am in need of having a referral in my site. In PHP it would look like this: `www.mysite.com/join?ref=100` and then on the page you would `$_get(ref);` 
Zend does not like this, so how do I implement this.

The second question is how can I have a subdomain on my site with the framework. I want to put a forum on my site, and tried a subdomain and loaded it, but it will not work as Zend pushes everything through the `index.php`. So how do I make it exist on the same site. I cannot put it in a module because it is a site within itself. Short of using another domain I am stuck.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you want to use subdomains you may want to use virtual host.

Comment: Zend likes it ;) Don't let anyone tell you different ;)

Answer (score 2):

Getting GET parameters such as www.mysite.com/join?ref=100 should work normally. Assuming that `join` is your controller and `index` is your action in that controller that paratmeter `ref` could be obtained using:

```
    var_dump($_GET['ref']);
    // or
    var_dump($this->getRequest()->getParam('ref'));
```

So I don't see a reason why ZF would not like it.

Unfortunately I cannot help you with the second question, as I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

For your second question about subdomains, there seem to be three issues:

1. Network-level routing
2. App-level routing
3. Module structure

At the network level, you would configure your hosting environment so that all the subdomains point to a single folder in your hosting environment. Then deploy as standard ZF installation there, including the standard `.htaccess`.

At the app level, your single ZF install will be receiving requests for all your subdomains. You can then use ZF's app-routing mechanism to handle those requests. In particular, you could configure various [Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.hostname) routes to handle the requests with your selected controllers/actions.

The last bit is which controllers and actions? It sounds like a good idea to create a separate module for each subdomain.  So the Hostname routes above can detect the subdomain and handle the request with the appropriate module (and controller/action).

Answer (score 1):

you should edit mod_rewrite rules in .htaccess

here is my rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

#do not rewrite for existing files and content of css, js, skin, forum subfolders
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(css|js|skin|forum)/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [L]


RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```