# how to point different domains to different modules?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have an application with multiple modules.
 Every module is a  different website in it.
 I want to point every module with different host/domain/subdomain name.
 Is it possible to do so?
 And if yes how to do so?

Comment: Are the modules running on different ports?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5282922/131824

Comment: everything is hosted on single server on godaddy.com

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution

```
[routes]

;; Domain config
routes.site1.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname"
routes.site1.abstract = true
routes.site1.route = "site1.localhost"
routes.site1.defaults.module = "default"

routes.site2.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname"
routes.site2.abstract = true
routes.site2.route = "site2.localhost"
routes.site2.defaults.module = "default2"

;; Home Page
routes.inicial.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
routes.inicial.abstract = true
routes.inicial.route = "inicio"
routes.inicial.defaults.controller = index
routes.inicial.defaults.action = index

routes.site1-inicial.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Chain"
routes.site1-inicial.chain = "site1,inicial"
routes.site2-inicial.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Chain"
routes.site2-inicial.chain = "site2,inicial"
```